# Question about: Prove that $\phi : \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (A_i,T_i)$ onto $[0,1]$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, product-space

**My question is:  How does choosing $N$ sufficiently large effect this proof?**

> Prove that $\phi : \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (A_i,T_i)$ onto $[0,1]$ is
>   continuous.

Let each $(A_i,T_i) = (\{0,2\}, T_{discrete})$ and $\phi (<a_1, a_2, ...>) = \sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \frac{a_i}{2^{i+1}}$.

Then to prove it is continuous show that if $U$ is the open interval $$\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \frac{a_i}{2^{i+1}} \in (\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \frac{a_i}{2^{i+1}} - \epsilon, \sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \frac{a_i}{2^{i+1}} + \epsilon)$$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ then there exists an open set $(<a_1, a_2, ...>) \in W$ such that $\phi (W) \subseteq U$.

Choose $N$ sufficiently large such that $\sum^{\infty}_{i=N} \frac{a_i}{2^{i+1}} \lt \epsilon$ and put $W = \{a_1\} \times \{a_2\} \times ... \times \{a_N\} \times A_{N+1} \times ...$

Then $W$ is open in  $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (A_i,T_i)$, $<a_1, a_2, ...> \in W$, and $\phi (W) \subseteq U$, as required.

Comment: Do you understand why $\phi(W) \subset U$?

Comment: $\phi (\{a_1\} \times ... \times \{a_N\} \times A_{N+1} \times ...) = \frac{a_1}{2^{1+1}} + ... + \frac{a_N}{2^{N+1}} + \frac{a_{N+1}}{2^{N+1}} + ...$ where each  $\frac{a_{N+i}}{2^{N+i}} \lt \epsilon$.  I think I'm not understanding what to do with the $A_{N+i}$.

Comment: @ArcticChar How do you define $\phi(W) = \phi (<a_1, a_2, ..., a_N, A_{N+1}, A_{N+2}, ...)$ I don't understand when it maps to the sets.